# Is there any benefit to using CakePHP Configure class over storing configurations as global constants?

Tags: php, cakephp

For instance, I have a separate configuration file that I am loading into my core.php file via -

```
require 'config_file.php';
```

In this file currently I have things like -

```
define('DOWN', false);
define('SUPPORT_EMAIL', 'shepard@normandy.com');
```

etc...  Is there any benefit to using the configure class to store these instead?

```
Configure::write('App.down', false);
Configure::write('App.support_email', 'shepard@normandy.com');
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constants pollute the global space, while the `Configure` class has its own space inside of the global space.

Also the `Configure` class can store any type of data, while constants can only hold only scalar values (arrays are supported as of PHP7).

Additionally the `Configure` class

- can change values at runtime
- can merge array structures
- allows easy dot notation access
- fails silently (returns `null` for non existent variables/paths, where as constants trigger a notice and return a the requested constants name as a string)
- can fail hard (trigger an exception) if requested to
- etc..

Also by using framework techniques you are doing every CakePHP developer that is going to work on your project a huge favour.

Knowing all that it's up to you to decide what's best for you and project.